# get grid Id from store in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I have some problem in EXTJS ,I really appreciate if someone help me
Did someone get grid id from it's store?I have some grid and I should get their id from theirs stores.
thank you

Comment: a store can be bound to multiple grids. the data layer should know nothing of the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I think the store doesn't know what it is bound to.

For me, you can't get a grid Id from a store Id.